# Iterating over CombBox.Items in a thread-safe manner

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

How would one iterate over a C# WinForms ComboBox.Items collection (see the code below for an example) in a thread-safe manner? With collections I control locking can be used, but I don't control the comboBox.Items collections since it is updated by its data binding source (and if I want to keep this method reusable I can't interact with any specific data binding sources in this code). There's a comboBox.Items.CopyTo method but I would need to create an array first and the count might change between creating the array and performing the copy?

Thanks for any advice.

```
private void SetComboBoxWidth(ComboBox comboBox, bool setDropDownWidth)
{
    int maxWidth = 0;
    using (Graphics graphics = comboBox.CreateGraphics())
    {
        foreach (object item in comboBox.Items)
        {
            int curWidth = TextRenderer.MeasureText(graphics, item.ToString(), comboBox.Font).Width;
            if (curWidth > maxWidth)
            {
                maxWidth = curWidth;
            }
        }
    }
    maxWidth += SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth;

    if (setDropDownWidth)
    {
        comboBox.DropDownWidth = maxWidth;
    }
    else
    {
        comboBox.Width = maxWidth;
    }
}
```

Edit:
The code above throws: {System.InvalidOperationException} Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

The combobox was set up with:

```
myComboBox.ComboBox.DataSource = new BindingList<IMyInterface>();
```

And the call chain is: MyForm.OnLoad->MyForm.Setup->MyForm.SetComboBoxWidth

Edit 2:
Changed example code to not alter ComboBox at all during the loop (previous version would potentially adjust the Width on each iteration).

Comment: WinForms is single-threaded. It's always thread-safe if you don't directly do anything in another thread. It means that, even if data source updates are made in another thread, updates are dispatched in the correct UI thread. Of course enumeration will fail if you change comboBox.Items inside foreach loop but this is true for any enumeration...

Comment: @Adriano
The example code above throws:
Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute. {System.InvalidOperationException}

Comment: Throws what exactly? - EDIT: too slow in typing

Comment: So question is...what's your data source? When/how you invoke SetComboBoxWidth()?

Comment: The combobox was set up with:
myComboBox.ComboBox.DataSource = new BindingList<IMyInterface>();

And SetComboBoxWidth is called from a chain of methods that ultimately starts in an overriden WndProc on my main form.

Comment: And the second part of Adrianos question: _When/how you invoke SetComboBoxWidth()?_

Comment: Sorry keep hitting enter for new line and posting instead. Edited answer in now. :)

Comment: I've just checked in VS and the chain for the crash is actually:
MyForm.OnLoad->MyForm.Setup->MyForm.SetComboBoxWidth

Comment: Please update your question and post the functions `MyForm.OnLoad` and `MyForm.Setup` as well

Answer (score 0):

You **shouldn't** update UI in multiple threads. If you follow this rule you don't need to worry about thread-safety as they are updated only by "Main Thread".

If at all you need to update UI in another thread, you'll pass the control to UI thread using `Control.Invoke` or `Control.BeginInvoke`.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question in case anyone else encounters this problem, although I don't have a full understanding of what was happening.

The IMyInterface objects stored in the BindingList also implement INotifyPropertyChanged. A background thread can change a property in an IMyInterface object causing an INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged to occur. When the property of an object in a BindingList DataSource changes, ComboBox recreates its list (I *think* that's what happens anyway, not sure). If this happens while the foreach is iterating then a InvalidOperationException is thrown.

I worked around this problem by creating a subclass of BindingList that overrides OnListChanged to Invoke if necessary. This seems to have solved the problem.

Thanks to the people who answered and commented and pointed in the right direction.